# Optimize redundant processing for dynamic columns in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

Currently, I am building a dynamic table in which both row and column values are determined at runtime. I have achieved this through following code.

```
{{#each item in collection}}
<tr>
   {{#each field in fields}} // redundant for all collections
   <td>
     {{sample-td field=field data=item}}
   </td>
   {{/each}}
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Now, this works well but for large data sets, the rendering seems too slow. On analyzing the code, it seems the 2nd loop is processing redundantly accross the 1st loop ( the fields only have to be calculated once but it is calculating it across each value of the collection).

Please suggest on how I can optimize my code.

Comment: You can show code piece where you are dynamically setting fields property.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify key value to improve rendering speed in consecutive rendering.
Follow [Ember guide link](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_each)

```
{{#each model key="id" as |item|}}
{{/each}}
```